# How to find domain object relationed classes parameter?

Tags: grails

I have domain classes workpackage, activity and aw. 
How to get activity id value from workpackage.

```
class Aw {

    Activity activity    
    static hasMany=[activity:Activity]    
    Workpackage workpackage 

    static belongsTo=[workpackage:Workpackage]

    static constraints = {

        workpackage nullable:true    
        activity nullable:true
    }
}
```

Comment: If you format your question and clearly define what you need help with, along with the steps you have taken already, then you are more likely to receive the help you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workpackage has-many Activity. That's it. No PW or AW classes. When you want Project ID from activity, just write 
`def myactivity = Activity.get(passed_id);
def wanted_id = my_activity.workpackage.project.id.`

 
If I didn't understand the question properly, please explain more thoroughly.

Comment: What is the purpose of PW and AW classes? What are you trying to achieve generally? Explain that and I can give you some pointers, because this approach is not the best.

Comment: Grails uses Hibernate. And Hibernate is a framework, that does a lot for you. If you set those relations (hasmany and belongsto), you don't need to create another class to "connect" them. What concerns connecting 3 domains - maybe the approach is wrong. Do you have projects in a workpackage and activities in project? If so - create relations between W and P; and P and A.

Comment: If I am not understanding the needed relations, explain briefly not using coding terms, but simple words.

Comment: Again - Do you have projects in a workpackage and activities in project? What is the desired relationship between project and activity? You are just explaining it chaotically, hard to understand.

Comment: You don't get it, do you? Explain how project should be connected to activities!!! For example, I am explaining different thing. There are Team, Player and Exercise. Each team has multiple players, each player has multiple exercises, but one exercise can be done by multiple players. Team-Player and Player-Exerc connected with has-many. Each exercise has attribute Team (no relations, just attribute from class team). Explain the same way.

Comment: then just go with Project has-many Workpackage. Workpackage has-many Activity. That's it. **No PW or AW classes**. 
When you want Project ID from activity, just write `def myactivity = Activity.get(passed_id); def wanted_id = my_activity.workpackage.project.id`.

Comment: That's a new question. Leave the stackoverflow clean.

Comment: I changed my answer. Could You accept it to close this topic?

Comment: By my answer (to the left of the 0 as the vote) is grey checkmark. Click it to accept my question as the answer, so this post would close!